# How to display stored value of datetimepicker to blade in Laravel

Tags: laravel, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

Do you know guys how display the date value from database to datetimepicker field?

the example value from database is **2022-10-31**

```
<div class="input-group date" id="allDay" data-target-input="nearest">
    <input type="text" id="all-value" name="all_day"
        class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#allDay"
        value="" />
    <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#allDay" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
         <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js

```
$('#allDay,#startLongDay,#endLongDay').datetimepicker({
    format: 'L',
    minDate: new Date()
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the jQuery DateTime Picker, You can retrieve the value from the database and then pass it to the view through your controller. After that, you can set it as the `value` attribute.

Example:

```html
<input type="text" id="all-value" name="all_day"
        class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#allDay"
        value="{{$date}}" />
```

Or else you can do it in JS Way:

1. Setting with `viewDate` option

```js
<script>
var d = "{{$date}}"
$('#allDay,#startLongDay,#endLongDay').datetimepicker('viewDate', d);
</script>
```

2. Setting with `date` option

```js
<script>
var d = "{{$date}}"
$('#allDay,#startLongDay,#endLongDay').datetimepicker('date', d);
</script>
```

Please note that in all of the above steps you need to format the date correctly.

Comment: it showing the date in value="" but not displaying in input field of datetimepicker

Comment: Okay. I made an update to the answer.